# setting Visual Studio to help me better document my code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, class

What I am trying to do is setup Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to have it help me keep track of my code architecture better.  I am running on Windows 8.1 if that makes any difference.  An example will (hopefully) demonstrate what I mean:

If I want to use the sine function, Visual Studio insists that I pre-pend Math. in front of it:   Rise = Math.sin(Angle)

What I want to do is have the same behavior for libraries that I have created.  I have created a class called K2Math  (called out as Public Class K2Math) and in it are functions like:  Public Shared Function CheckForCollinear( . . . ) as Boolean.  I have bundled it up into a separate DLL.

In my caller code, in the project references I have a reference to K2Math.DLL. As the functions are Public Shared, I don't have to use 'New K2Math' setup call like I would with a more conventional DLL.  However, in the caller program I can use the CheckForCollinear function without having to pre-pend K2Math.  I can also call it using K2Math.CheckForCollinear and the compiler doesn't complain.

What I would like the compiler to do is complain and force me to pre-pend the K2Math.  This would help to make it obvious to me or whoever is reading my code how the code is architected and segregated.

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  Also, I haven't figured out how to succinctly pose the question to do a proper Google search.

If I am being unclear, please so note that and I'll try to clear things up.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us. Members of a class must be qualified, either explicitly or implicitly. What you describe is, as far as I'm aware, simply not possible. If you can invoke a member without explicit qualification, i.e. using just `SomeMember` rather than `SomeType.SomeMember` or `SomeVariable.SomeMember`, then it must be a member of the current type, a member of a module rather than a class or else you have actually imported that type, rather than just the namespace it's a member of.  TBC...

Comment: Cont... For instance, if you have a class and in the code file for that class you add `Imports System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`, you can then call just `Show` rather than `MessageBox.Show`.  If you only import the namespace, i.e. `System.Windows.Forms`, then you must call `MessageBox.Show`.  I suspect that you have actually defined a module rather than a class, in which case members are implicitly `Shared` and do not require qualification when invoked.

Comment: You are missing name space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Library lets say CustomizedMathLibrary
2. In that create a class K2Math. **WRAP in a NAME SPACE (This is important)**
3. Build and Use It by Importing name space in your code.

Comment: Thank you, Ramankingdom, that did it.  Just what I was looking for.  I had never used Namespace before - got along fine without it and never saw the need for it.  Now I see a bit of its utility.  This fix will help me make my code more readable and understandable.  I appreciate your taking the time to comment and helping me get one rung higher on the ladder of learning VB.Net.

Comment: Please mark it as answer